# Labeling numbers on points in row close together using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, point

[image: the row with points which need the number-labels nearby]

In my map I have 76 points aligned on a row. Now I would like to force label **each** point with an attribute number. I don't mind how far the label is from the point as long that it is shown but of course the closer the better.

In [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/) I found the option of Manhattan-lines but for what I saw is that I've to manually tell how far the label is from the point. I don't want that.

Any ideas or tips?

I'm looking for something like a dynamic placement of the labels. As close as possible to the points but not overlapping each other.

Comment: In qgis you can label each points with the attribute of your choice. go in layer's property > labeling > choose the property for your label.

Comment: yes I understand that. But I want from one attribute-class, all the points labelled. As you can imagine, on the image I added, on the left you see 229, 227, 225 is missing, 223, 221 is missing, 219, ... . Now i want 225 and 221 'somewhere' nearby and visible without overlapping other labels

Comment: If the problem is that some labels are hidden because conflicting with other, you can try to  check "Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)" in the rendering menu of the label.

Answer (score 3):

Sort your points spatially along line. Compute line bearing and use it as rotation angle for label. Define 2 label classes, e.g.

```
mod( "FID",2)=0 and mod( "FID",2)=1
```

Play with x-shift and font size in symbol properties to get this:

[image]